# Git how to not include specific file(s) to commit

Tags: git, gitignore, git-commit

Im trying to not include some files to be commit. For example, I don't want any change in the following files to be included in a commit:

```
bootstrap/start.php
```

So I include them in ***.gitignore*** like this:

```
/bootstrap/compiled.php
/bootstrap/start.php
/vendor
composer.phar
composer.lock
.env.local.php
.env.php
.DS_Store
Thumbs.db.idea
.idea/
/public/dbase
/public/user_images
/app/config/lenovo
```

but when Im running `git status` I still get this message:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   .gitignore
    modified:   bootstrap/start.php

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

How to do that? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bootstrap/start.php is already tracked by git.

from the gitignore docs "A gitignore file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git should ignore. Files already tracked by Git are not affected; see the NOTES below for details."

Comment: what is that mean? will any changes in bootstrap/start.php still commited ?

Comment: it means that you have added bootstrap/start.php to the git repository and git is tracking the changes to the file. You can tell git to stop ignore changes to a tracked file via the command
```git update-index --assume-unchanged bootstrap/start.php``` and you can then restart tracking of those changes with ```git update-index --no-assume-unchanged bootstrap/start.php```

Comment: `git update-index --assume-unchanged bootstrap/start.php` this works, if I run `git status` the **bootstrap/start.php** not listed anymore ... thank you sir :) . I don't want any change in that file tracked by git so I don't need to run `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged bootstrap/start.php` right?

Comment: Yep...only run that if you want to reenable tracking of changes sometime in the future

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged bootstrap/start.php
```